# Delete the first periodic digit

Tags: code-golf, math, rational-numbers

We all know that whenever a rational number is written in decimal, the result is either terminating or (eventually) periodic. For example, when 41/42 is written in decimal, the result is

```
0.9 761904 761904 761904 761904 761904 761904 761904 ...
```

with an initial sequence of digits `0.9` followed by the sequence `761904` repeated over and over again. (A convenient notation for this is `0.9(761904)` where the parentheses surround the block of repeating digits.)

Your goal in this challenge is to take a positive rational number, delete the first digit that's part of the repeating sequence, and return the resulting rational number. For example, if we do this to 41/42, we get

```
0.9  61904 761904 761904 761904 761904 761904 761904 ...
```

or `0.9(619047)` for short, which is 101/105.

If the rational number has a terminating decimal expansion, like 1/4 = `0.25` does, nothing should happen. You can think of 1/4 either as `0.250000000...` or as `0.249999999...` but in either case, deleting the first digit of the repeating part leaves the number unchanged.

### Details

- The input is a positive rational number, either as a pair of positive integers representing the numerator and denominator, or (if your language of choice allows it and you want to) as some sort of rational-number object.
- The output is also a rational number, also in either form. If the result is an integer, you may return the integer instead of a rational number.
- If taking a pair of numbers as input, you may assume they're relatively prime; if producing a pair of numbers as output, you must make them be relatively prime.
- Be careful that you find the *first* digit that starts a repeating block. For example, one could write 41/42 as `0.97(619047)` but that doesn't make 2041/2100 (with the decimal expansion `0.97(190476)`) a valid answer.
- You may assume that in the input you get, the first periodic digit is *after* the decimal point, making `120/11` = `10.909090909...` invalid input: (its first periodic digit could be considered the `0` in `10`). You may do anything you like on such input.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf): the shortest solution wins.

### Test cases

```
41/42 => 101/105
101/105 => 193/210
193/210 => 104/105
104/105 => 19/21
1/3 => 1/3
1/4 => 1/4
2017/1 => 2017/1
1/7 => 3/7
1/26 => 11/130
1234/9999 => 2341/9999
```

Comment: Can we return `2017` instead of `2017/1`?

Comment: Yes, if you're doing the rational number thing. (If you're doing the pair-of-integers thing, then I'm not sure what else you'd return except the pair `(2017,1)`.)

Comment: May the input be reducible (not fully simplified)? For example, can `2/4` happen in the input?

Comment: If input is `120/11` is the correct answer `111/11` or `210/11`?

Comment: @user202729 You may assume that the input is a fully simplified rational number.

Comment: @kasperd Huh, that's a case I hadn't thought of...  I'd want to say `111/11` except that the most highly upvoted answer at the moment returns `210/11`, so I will let you pick to avoid invalidating existing answers.

Comment: @MishaLavrov alternatively, you could specify that all inputs will be between 0 and 1. (It should only affect the `2017/1` case)

Comment: @JungHwanMin There is an infinite number of rational numbers between 0 and 1 for which the question would also apply. I think the simplest example would be `10/11`.

Comment: @kasperd The zero (ones place) in `0.(90)` isn't significant, so including it in the repeating sequence wouldn't really make sense.

Answer (score 12):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 59 bytes

```
FromDigits@MapAt[RotateLeft@*List@@#&,RealDigits@#,{1,-1}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYqxCsIwFEX3/Eahg0ReXhItHYQI4lRBuopDkKQGjJX2baXfHhPoHQ73Hm609HbRUnjZ5E/pOo3xEoZAs7nZ35ke/UiWXOc8mV0XZjKmqnnv7Gd7VXxBvsf1Waf7FL755cEsjGkELTlDgYDikEurQKIoRm8GVIHmTApsAMtoCuQxUyoNbQ5ja/oD)

#### Explanation

```
RealDigits@#
```

Find the decimal digits of the input.

```
MapAt[RotateLeft@*List@@#&, ..., {1,-1}]
```

If there are repeating digits, `RotateLeft` them. (`List@@#` prevents the code from attempting to rotate the last decimal digit if the rational number is terminating).

```
FromDigits@
```

Convert to rational.

Comment: Very clever indeed!

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>36</s> <s>32</s> <s>31</s> 30 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [*Erik the Outgolfer*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer)!

```
ọ2,5Ṁ⁵*©×Ɠ÷µ×⁵_Ḟ$+Ḟ,®×³+.Ḟ÷g/$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7l4jHdOHOxseNW7VOrTy8PRjkw9vP7T18HQgP/7hjnkq2kBC59C6w9MPbdbWA7IPb0/XV/n/39DI2OS/JRAAAA)

Should be correct. Floating point imprecision add 3 bytes for `+.Ḟ`.

Relies on the input being irreducible.

---

### Explanation

This relies on:

- Let the numerator be `n/d` in its simplest form. Then the link `ọ2,5Ṁ` applied to `d` will give the number of non-periodic digit after the radix point.

```
ọ2,5Ṁ⁵*©×Ɠ÷µ×⁵_Ḟ$+Ḟ,®×³+.Ḟ÷g/$     Main link (monad take d as input)

    Ṁ                              Maximum
ọ                                  order of
 2,5                               2 or 5 on d
     ⁵*                            10 power
       ©                           Store value to register ®.
        ×Ɠ                         Multiply by eval(input()) (n)
          ÷                        Divide by first argument (d).
                                   Now the current value is n÷d×®.
           µ                       With that value,
            ×⁵                     Multiply by ⁵ = 10
              _Ḟ$                  subtract floor of self
                 +Ḟ                add floor or value (above)
                                   Given 123.45678, will get 123.5678
                                   (this remove first digit after `.`)
                   ,®              Pair with ®.
                     ×³            Scale
                       +.Ḟ         Round to integer
                          ÷g/$     Simplify fraction
```

Comment: [30 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7l4jHdOHOxseNW7VOrTy8PRjkw9vP7T18HQgP/7hjnkq2kBC59C6w9MPbdbWA7IPb0/XV/n/39DI2OS/JRAAAA)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>237</s> <s>235</s> 214 bytes

<sup>-21 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder</sup>

```python
from fractions import*
F=Fraction
n,d=input()
i=n/d
n%=d
R=[]
D=[]
while~-(n in R):R+=n,;n*=10;g=n/d;n%=d;D+=g,
x=R.index(n)
r=D[x+1:]+[D[x]]
print i+F(`r`[1::3])/F('9'*len(r))/10**x+F("0."+"".join(map(str,D[:x])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYvBisMgFEX3foUESn3qJLFdDDW4C/mAbEVomaStQ/MU6zDOZn4908BsDpfDPfEn3wMe1vWawkKv6fKRfcAn9UsMKXMymOHfEZST8Ri/MgPiDTYTwZ2ZyGisI/2G77t/zL9vDKlHOoIehUHZITeq7W5b0G1B1wtzk6SYsfY4zYUhkGR6W4TSTtjXcI7E5DFTLwZ2TmertD46aAa2P@35Y0aWABrVcl5eh6qtK1FV9WfwyJZLZM@cZG91cQCwruzQqndJFfwB)

Input is done as a tuple `(numerator, denominator)`; output is a `fractions.Fraction` object.

This uses a long-division-style method to get the starting and repeating digits of the answer, then moves the first repeating digit to the end and uses string manipulation and `fraction.Fraction` to convert it back to a ratio.

Ungolfed version:

```python
import fractions

num, denom = input()
integer_part, num = divmod(num, denom)

remainders = []
digits = []
current_remainder = num
while current_remainder not in remainders:
    remainders.append(current_remainder)
    current_remainder *= 10
    digit, current_remainder = divmod(current_remainder, denom)
    digits.append(digit)

remainder_index = remainders.index(current_remainder)
start_digits = digits[:remainder_index]
repeated_digits = digits[remainder_index:]

repeated_digits.append(repeated_digits.pop(0))

start_digits_str = "".join(map(str, start_digits))
repeated_digits_str = "".join(map(str, repeated_digits))

print(integer_part+int(repeated_digits_str)/fractions.Fraction('9'*(len(repeated_digits_str)))/10**len(start_digits_str)+fractions.Fraction("0."+start_digits_str))
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>177</s> <s>173</s> 169 bytes

```python
from fractions import*
def f(n,d):
 i=1;r=[]
 while~-(i%d in r):r+=[i%d];i*=10
 r=10**r.index(i%d);u=i-r;v=i//r-1;t=u//d*n
 return Fraction(t-t%v+t%v*10//v+t%v*10%-~v,u)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BDoIwFET3nOJvSNpCrVVWNN16CcLC2Db8RAr5FtQNV8ea6GIm85KXzPxOwxTP@x5oGiHQ9ZZwig/AcZ4oicL5AIHF2vG2ALTakO36Ap4D3v0mGZYOMALxlirbZeoNCquPBVBuIeiA0fnX1@NmsSjJrBaVIqlNsotSTsTs@rRQhMvvnSWZyrXKEfqo1H@Vclvrhe8zYUwssEbXzYnz/QM)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder edited

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>70</s> 67 bytes

Thanks to [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/38422) (now deleted) for -3 byte!

```
(x=10^Max@IntegerExponent[#,{2,5}];(Floor@#+Mod[10#,1])/x&[x#2/#])&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc1BC4IwGMbxe59CGIjSwL1zJiKCl4IOQvexYOQsIbeQHQbRZ1@7BJPe2//HA@8i7UMt0s436afOZ64Dch2k68/aqrtaj@5ltNKWI/ymuPqINjs9jVl7tB/MyIEgDCIvXModogUSeeov66xtP3FGccJAtLsfAKlwAiQmCiRQU/6vWERlgCjZNgEnlEAdSb0d0MO2m3BBaBl@@C8)

A port of my [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150851). Longer than the existing Mathematica answer by 8 bytes...

The function take 2 input `[denominator, numerator]`, such that `GCD[denominator, numerator] == 1`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 102 bytes

```perl6
{$/=.base-repeating;(+$0//$0~0)+([~]([$1.comb].rotate)/(9 x$1.chars)*.1**(($0~~/\.<(.*/).chars)if $1)}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##fZDdboMwDIXveQpLQ2tC1TghGQhlvd0D7LarpkDTjWmFip9pVVVenUFBayeV@c4@n4@ts7fFZ9DWpYWvgCXa2R3gPsk3Fpbt0cUli01pF4XdW1Ol2Zsmc5cjurzhdE5WzZqsXMGSfBevWZFXprIUSQTf/fDdFCX1mPA8QrqFBl/YI2Ee0lFKt@AKemrLOgZTLraFSao0z4DAk6meTUUouK9A4QgsqzeWfeRpRmY4o3BynNIc/iydX1YCla@hrzsQXKDgD7fJUdQDGUn0BZ8gB3EkufrPU117dlsTHMrhxzOHcopS15S6TflchCj0QA3NlF14sZMYTlF@oH@PdhHJqVR8qTDqSvd3ZRd837Q/)

Takes a [Rational](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Rational) number and returns a [Rational](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Rational) or [Int](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Int) number.

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit Rational parameter ｢$_｣

  $/ = .base-repeating; # store in ｢$/｣ the two strings '0.9' '761904'

    # handle the non-repeating part
    (
      +$0        # turn into a number
      // $0 ~ 0  # if that fails append 0 (handle cases like '0.')
    )

  +

    # handle the repeating part
    (
          [~]( [$1.comb].rotate ) # rotate the repeating part
        /
          ( 9 x $1.chars )        # use a divisor that will result in a repeating number

        *

         # offset it an appropriate amount

         .1 ** (
           ( $0 ~~ / \. <( .* / ).chars # count the characters after '.'
         )

      if $1  # only do the repeating part if there was a repeating part
    )
}
```

Note will handle denominators upto `uint64.Range.max` to handle larger denominators use `FatRat(9 x$1.chars)` [Try it](https://tio.run/##fZDNboMwEITvPMVKRY1NFK@NXRByc@0D9JpGlSFOS9VAxE/VKAqvTiGgJpVC97aab2ZXs7fFZ9DWpYWvgCXa2R3gPsk3Fpbt0cUli01pF4XdW1Ol2Zsmc5cjurzhdE5WzZqsXMGSfBevWZFXprIUn0z1bCoSwXcvvZuipB4TnkdIZ2vwhT0S5iEdpXQLrqCntqxjMOViW5ikSvMMCIw5FNxXoHAEltUbyz7yNCMznFE4OU5pDn9M58eVQOVr6OcOBBco@MNtchT1QEYSfcEnyEEcSa7@y1TXmZ1rgkM5/HjmUE5R6ppStymfixCFHqhhmYoLL3ESwynKD/Tv0a4iOdWKLxVG3ej@ruyK75f2Bw).